# Como descargar un archivo con PuppeteerSharp c# Headless true

Tags: c#

Necesito descargar un archivo generado de un sistema web. La cual luego de seleccionar varios filtros se da clic al boton exportar, este boton abre una ventana,genera un excel, descargar y cierra automaticamente la venta. Mi codigo hace todo los proceso, pero la descargar no se realiza y no da error.
Adjunto parte del codigo:

```
public static async Task DescargarExcel(string BtnFiltro, string CampoFecha)
    {
        var itemrole_main = Frametab_1003?.ChildFrames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "role_main");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        var item_cai_main = itemrole_main?.ChildFrames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "cai_main");

        if (item_cai_main != null)
        {
            await item_cai_main.TypeAsync("input[id='sf_0_3']", "%genesys%");
            await item_cai_main.QuerySelectorAsync($"#{BtnFiltro}").Result.ClickAsync();

            await Task.Delay(2000);

            var fechainicio = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-Extras.SETTINGS.MesesConsultaSolicitud);
            var txtfecha = $"{fechainicio.FormatoSeparador("/", Validacion.FormatoFecha.DDMMYYYY)} 12:00 am";

            await item_cai_main.TypeAsync($"input[id='{CampoFecha}']", txtfecha);
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            for (var i = 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                await item_cai_main.SelectAsync("#sf_1_2", i.ToString());
                await item_cai_main.QuerySelectorAsync("#imgBtn0").Result.ClickAsync();
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                await item_cai_main.QuerySelectorAsync("#imgBtn4").Result.ClickAsync();
                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }
```

El bóton #imgBtn4 es el que abre la ventana y descarga el archivo.
El proceso hace lo siguente, busca un frame dentro del html, de encontrarlo, escribo un texto e indica una fecha. Estos son para filtrar la información con la que se generar el excel. El for hace solo dos ciclos ya que se debe generar el excel con dos estados distintos. El boton imgBtn0 realiza la busqueda. Al tener los datos en pantalla recien se puede descargar el excel.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Ricardo, así como está formulada tu pregunta, no queda claro que necesitas, por otro lado, para poder ayudarte necesitamos ver tu código, te sugiero que edites la pregunta y agregues el mismo como texto, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Quizá la descarga no se realiza porque el navegador se cierra antes de que le des tiempo de descargarse.

Comment: Hola, Gracias, pero aun dandole 5 minutos, no descargar nada.